# How to set NIC configuration for Hyper-V machines only in MDT 2013 inside bootstrap.ini?

Tags: hyper-v, mdt, mdt-2013

I'm setting up an image factory in MDT and because our network is structured such that VM's won't receive a DHCP lease we have to apply NIC settings inside `bootstrap.ini`. This is only so when we load a test environment in Hyper-V, the virtual machine can connect to our deployment share.

Unfortunately we can only seem to apply this in the `bootstrap.ini` file not `customsettings.ini`. I have tried to add a registry for VM's in the MDT database to apply NIC configuration but I believe the only way we can configure the VM to connect to the database in the first place (at least, the MDT deployment share) is if it gets the NIC config in `bootstrap.ini`.

Though this works, it sets the default IP address to `xxx.xxx.xxx.128` for all machines receiving a LiteTouch installation which is unideal (we have many more physical computers that this affects) as we have to manually reconfigure the NIC after installation.

So my question is this: how can I apply NIC settings in `bootstrap.ini` to **only** affect VM's?

Thanks kindly.

Comment: I could have sworn that you can filter by `MAC` address in the settings processor (`bootstrap` and/or `customsettings`). If that is truly the case then you can find the `MAC` addresses that `Hyper-V` is generating from (there is a section in settings that defines the `MAC` address pool that it generates from) and assign your `NIC`settings based upon the `MAC` findings.

Comment: This should satisfy your requirements:https://scriptimus.wordpress.com/2012/03/27/mdt-2012-targeting-lite-touch-deployments/

Comment: Here is the official documentation for the make variable/selector: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn781091.aspx#Make

You could use this in place of the MAC filtering method. It should be more dynamic.

Comment: Thanks @ElliotLabs. I found it has to be in `bootstrap.ini` - I guess it can't get to `customsettings.ini` unless it has proper network configuration (given by `bootstrap.ini`). See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @ElliotLabs for referring me to Michael Niehaus helpful [guide](https://scriptimus.wordpress.com/2012/03/27/mdt-2012-targeting-lite-touch-deployments/).

I found that adding catch cases in `bootstrap.ini` works exactly as expected:

```
[Settings]
Priority=Model, Default 
Properties=MyCustomProperty

[Default]
SkipBDDWelcome=YES
DeployRoot=\\contoso.com\DeploymentShare$
UserID=xxx
UserPassword=xxx
UserDomain=xxx

[Virtual Machine]
OSDAdapter0EnableDHCP=False
OSDAdapterCount=1
OSDAdapter0IPAddressList=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
OSDAdapter0SubnetMask=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
OSDAdapter0Gateways=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
OSDAdapter0DNSServerList=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
OSDAdapter0Name=LAN
OSDAdapter0DNSSuffix=contoso.com
```

Note that `Virtual Machine` is the model name for Hyper-V VMs.
Also, in our organisation, VMs won't get DHCP, so it's important to disable it. Not sure if that is a global setting though.

Comment: Glad to be of service!